# What is octet meant in iCalendar Specification

Tags: calendar, icalendar

> Lines of text SHOULD NOT be longer than 75 octets, excluding the line break.  Long content lines SHOULD be split into a multiple line representations using a line "folding" technique.  That is, a long line can be split between any two characters by inserting a CRLF immediately followed by a single linear white-space character (i.e., SPACE or HTAB). [iCalendar Specification 3.1.Content Lines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-8)

What is meant by octet here?
Does it mean number of characters over here?

Answer (score 0):

No. It really means octet, as in 8bits. UTF-8 characters have a variable length (multi-octet). You have another hint here:

> Note: It is possible for very simple implementations to generate
>         improperly folded lines in the middle of a UTF-8 multi-octet
>         sequence.  For this reason, implementations need to unfold lines
>         in such a way to properly restore the original sequence.